# Get second value from array

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the second value from the array and label it `$icon` however I am still learning PHP. No matter what I try nothing has helped. This is for a WooCommerce website running a custom theme. The below code has been placed in the `functions.php` file.

```
$catalog_orderby = apply_filters('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
    'menu_order' => __( 'Default', '&#xf0dc;', 'woocommerce' ),
    'date'       => __( 'Whats New', '&#xf219;', 'woocommerce' ),
    'popularity' => __( 'Popularity', '&#xf087;', 'woocommerce' ),
    'rating'     => __( 'Average Rating', '&#xf123;', 'woocommerce' ),
    'price'      => __( 'Price: Low to High', '&#xf162;', 'woocommerce' ),
    'price-desc' => __( 'Price: High to Low', '&#xf163;', 'woocommerce' )
));

foreach( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) . '?orderby=' . $id . '"><i class="fa">' . $icon . '</i>' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</a></li>';
};
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__()` function seems to be for fetching a string translation, so you'd need to pass the icon string as a separate variable. You can do that using a multidimensional array.

```
$catalog_orderby = apply_filters('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
    'menu_order' => array(__( 'Default', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf0dc;'),
    'date'       => array(__( 'Whats New', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf219;'),
    'popularity' => array(__( 'Popularity', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf087;'),
    'rating'     => array(__( 'Average Rating', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf123;'),
    'price'      => array(__( 'Price: Low to High', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf162;'),
    'price-desc' => array(__( 'Price: High to Low', 'woocommerce' ), '&#xf163;')
));

foreach( $catalog_orderby as $id => $item ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) . '?orderby=' . $id . '"><i class="fa">' . $item[1] . '</i>' . esc_attr( $item[0] ) . '</a></li>';
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the _() function, it appears to be a translation function?

If you change the `__('Default', '&#xf0dc;', 'woocommerce')` to `array('Default', '&#xf0dc;', 'woocommerce')` you can access it in the loop by doing `$name[1]`

Comment: I see you are new here, welcome! Thank you very much for your help! I would mark both yours and S. Dev's answers as correct (as they are both the same) however I am unable to do so.

Comment: Thank you! His was both first and more correct, so I agree with it being the correct one.